# Illustrator CC equivalent to the InDesign Gap tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, spacing

Just wondering if there is an illustrator cc equivalent of the gap tool in InDesign? I find myself constantly tweaking the gaps between objects and its a bit fiddly. My method is usually to duplicate and command+D to create more copies the same spacing but it would be good to have a tool I can drag spacing in and out to see by eye if it works.

Comment: There's nothing equivalent in Illustrator

Comment: "Distribute spacing" in the "Align" palette might help with this.

Answer (score -2):

Use Figma. Figma is capable of many things that you may need in Illustrator and also have the gap tool feature.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/111260)

Comment: OP asked for a solution in a specific software. Saying they need to use a different software is not helpful, at all.